# GA4 Replacement Dimension for mcf:basicChannelGroupingPath

Tags: google-analytics-api

I've been scouring the docs for the API and can't find a replacement for mcf:basicChannelGroupingPath in GA4. There is sessionDefaultChannelGrouping but is only appears to grab the channel of the last touch (So Organic Search instead of Organic Search x2).

I've tried a request with

```
dimensions = [
'date',
'sessionDefaultChannelGrouping',
'eventName'
]

metrics = [
'conversions'
]
```

With the aim of getting a breakdown of the number of conversions per path per day. However the path part of it is not working.

Comment: Not all the dimensions in UA have a direct replacement in GA4